# Intellij Ideavim how to set key map for <ESC>

Tags: vim, intellij-idea

In my ~/.ideavimrc I set

```
noremap jj <Esc>
```

To remap "jj" to escape (to enter normal mode).

However it doesn't seem to be working? .ideavimrc is in the same location as my .vimrc and I restarted IntelliJ.

Comment: I don't believe multi key mappings work. I can't find an open ticket but thats what twitter comments suggest here https://twitter.com/ideavim/status/444201384981053441, http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-518

Comment: Thanks that explains A LOT...will try for another key.

Comment: @FDinoff can you make this an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe multi key mappings work. I can't find an open ticket but thats what twitter comments suggest here https://twitter.com/ideavim/status/444201384981053441, http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-518

You can also check which mappings intellij knows about by typing `:noremap`. Since `jj` shows up it probably doesn't work.

Comment: The current correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42366388/237059

Answer (score 31):

I found the solution on the ideaVim twitter page. To set jj to  you will need to include the following in your ~/.ideavimrc. This works for me using Jetbrains software. You need to set the timeoutlen so it know when to stop looking for the next char in the sequence.

```
imap jj <Esc>
set timeoutlen=1000
```

Twitter Link -- https://twitter.com/ideavim/status/512932112765562880?lang=en

Comment: It seems like no need to set timeout

Answer (score 26):

I am not aware whether something changed since this question was asked, but this works perfectly fine for me:

`imap jj <Esc>`

Comment: This works just needs restart of IDE, Thanks alot @Erick Johansson

Answer (score 23):

Add the following line in your `~/.ideavimrc`

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

Now reload `~/.ideavimrc`

```
:source ~/.ideavimrc
```

Check if your configurations work

```
:imap
```

You should see

> `i     jj          *  <Esc>`

If the configuration doesn't load next time you open your IDE, check how home works. You can read more about this in https://github.com/vlasovskikh/ideavim-vimscript/blob/master/help/txt/map.txt

Comment: This worked for me and saved lots of effort

Answer (score 1):

On the terminal App

```
   vim  ~/.ideavimrc
```

1. inside the file add the below

   ```
   imap jj <Esc>
   ```
2. save  via press esc key and then

   ```
   :w
   ```
3. press enter key
4. source the file by

   ```
    :source ~/.ideavimrc
   ```
5. quit vim via

   ```
    :q
   ```

**From there you are good to goo**